# How to set values into a selectradiobutton from a managed bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I´ve a datatable that has a column with selectoneradio, so I´m supposed to turn on the radios if they are on in my database. So I recover my data but I can´t figured how to tell my selectoneradio buttons to be on when my users consult the page with the table. Here is the code from my table:

```html
<p:dataTable id="secciones" var="secciones" value="#{seccionesMB.seccionesList}" style="width: 60%;">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{secciones.codigo}" />
            <f:facet name="header" >
                 <h:outputText value="Seccion" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{secciones.seccion}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
             <f:facet name="header">
                 <div align="left"> <h:outputText value="Alta &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Baja &nbsp; Consulta &nbsp; Mod &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; N/A" /></div>
             </f:facet>
            <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{secciones.nivel}" disabled="true">  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="10000" itemValue="10000" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="01000" itemValue="01000" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="00100" itemValue="00100" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="00010" itemValue="00010" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="00001" itemValue="00001" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>  
        </p:column>    
</p:dataTable>
```

and here is the method from my backing bean that feeds my datatable:

```
public String consultarPerfil(int id, String perfil) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.setPerfil(perfil);
    try {
        List<Perfiles_Secciones> list = getPerfiles_SeccionesService().getPerfiles_Seccion(id);
        int i = 0;
        for(SeccionesDTO seccionDTO : seccionesList) {
            for(Perfiles_Secciones ps : list) {
                if (seccionDTO.getId() == ps.getId_seccion()) {                            
                    System.out.println(seccionDTO.getId() + " - " + ps.getId_seccion());
                    seccionDTO.setNivel(ps.getNivel()); 
                }
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
        }
        for(SeccionesDTO seccionDTO : seccionesList) {
            System.out.println(seccionDTO.getNivel());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PerfilesManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return CONSULTAR_PERFIL;
}
```

What do I need to do in order to feed my selectoneradio from my managed bean??

Comment: Make sure `secciones.nivel` value matches some of the `itemValue`s of the items inside your radio button.

Comment: some are matching but they still aren´t turning them on

Comment: Are you sure `secciones.nivel` is a `String` and the *right* value is `equals(seccionesNivel)`?

Comment: i print on my xhtml secciones.nivel and it seems empty which is weird because according to my method consultarPerfil, there are values???

Comment: Now you know why this didn't work. Try to isolate the problem to find the culprit of these problems.

Comment: How/when do you call consultarPerfil method? You have seccionesList, that is displayed in you datatable and you fill it with nivels - and that is not displayed. That would mean you call consultarPerfil too late.